# OpenWrt no dmesg/lsusb when usb hid device is attached

Tags: linux, usb, openwrt

I am running OpenWrt on VirtualBox with host as Windows 10.
I have a USB - HID device which is attached to Windows host. I am making it available for the Guest OpenWrt. However, I don't see this in the OpenWrt. I don't see anything in the dmesg either.
I have also installed the kernel module for usb hid and its loaded.

Comment: did you install the client drivers for virtualbox in your VM?

Comment: Do you mean the usb-hid kernel module? Yes, I have